# Major issues with a query

Tags: sql

I have a query

```
SELECT 
  ZEML.ICC_CODE AS ICC_CODE 
 ,SUM(CS.TOT_HOURS) AS TOT_HOURS 
 ,SUM(CS.NUM_INCIDENT_ALL) AS NUM_INCIDENTS 
 ,(VALUE(FLOAT(SUM(CS.NUM_INCIDENT_ALL)) * 200000 / SUM(TOT_HOURS) 
 ,0)) AS INC_RATE 

 FROM TR.CLAIMS_SUMM CS 

INNER JOIN TR.LOCATION_MASTER LM 
   ON LM.LOCATION = CS.LOCATION 
  AND CS.LOCATION < '900' 

 LEFT JOIN TR.LOCATION_ASSIGNMENTS DISTRICT 
   ON DISTRICT.LOCATION = LM.LOCATION 
  AND DISTRICT.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'District' 

 LEFT JOIN TR.LOCATION_ASSIGNMENTS TERRITORY 
   ON TERRITORY.LOCATION = LM.LOCATION 
  AND TERRITORY.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'Territory' 

 LEFT JOIN TR.EMPL_CLAIMS ZEML 
   ON CS.LOCATION = ZEML.LOCATION 
  AND ZEML.TYPE = 'WC' 
  AND ZEML.STATUS <> 'V' 
  AND ZEML.CLAIM_ACTION NOT IN ('D','F','I','H') 

WHERE CS.DW_DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2014' 
  AND '05/31/2014' 
  AND (MONTH(ZEML.DATE_OF_INCIDENT) = MONTH(CS.DW_DATE) 
  AND YEAR(ZEML.DATE_OF_INCIDENT) = YEAR(CS.DW_DATE)) 

GROUP BY ZEML.ICC_CODE 

UNION 

SELECT 
'OTHER' AS ICC_CODE 
 , 0 AS TOT_HOURS 
 , 0 AS NUM_INCIDENTS 
 , 0 AS INC_RATE 

 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 

WHERE 1 = 1 

ORDER BY 1
```

in my union where I made an other I want to select everything else from the tr.empl_claims table and store it in the other from the union because this is what I have many other ICC codes without incidents on them and I am doing calculations on our incident rate and hourse based off of all the data but my query right now is only selecting the ones that currently is having incidents which is throwing off my calculations.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Looks like `DB2` database to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your use of `FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` I believe you are using `DB2` database. If yes, you can use CTE (common table expression) to achieve the desired result like

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
SELECT 
  ZEML.ICC_CODE AS ICC_CODE 
 ,SUM(CS.TOT_HOURS) AS TOT_HOURS 
 ,SUM(CS.NUM_INCIDENT_ALL) AS NUM_INCIDENTS 
 ,(VALUE(FLOAT(SUM(CS.NUM_INCIDENT_ALL)) * 200000 / SUM(TOT_HOURS) 
 ,0)) AS INC_RATE 

 FROM TR.CLAIMS_SUMM CS 

... <rest of the code> ...
)

select * from cte1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
ICC_CODE 
 , 0 AS TOT_HOURS 
 , 0 AS NUM_INCIDENTS 
 , 0 AS INC_RATE 
 FROM TR.EMPL_CLAIMS 
 WHERE ICC_CODE NOT IN 
 (
   SELECT distinct ICC_CODE
   FROM cte1 
 )
ORDER BY 1
```

SideNote: You are joining the same table `LOCATION_ASSIGNMENTS` twice (as below) which is not needed.

```
 LEFT JOIN TR.LOCATION_ASSIGNMENTS DISTRICT 
   ON DISTRICT.LOCATION = LM.LOCATION 
  AND DISTRICT.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'District' 

 LEFT JOIN TR.LOCATION_ASSIGNMENTS TERRITORY 
   ON TERRITORY.LOCATION = LM.LOCATION 
  AND TERRITORY.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'Territory'
```

This can be transformed to below using a `IN` operator

```
 LEFT JOIN TR.LOCATION_ASSIGNMENTS DISTRICT 
   ON DISTRICT.LOCATION = LM.LOCATION 
  AND DISTRICT.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE IN ('District', 'Territory')
```

See more about Common Table Expression in DB2 [Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg/src/tpc/db2z_createcte.dita).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped by clicking the check button under voting button.